# Как выполнять JS код в зависимости от id?

Tags: javascript

На одном сайте лежит файл `load.js`. 
На втором сайте хочу выполнить этот скрипт, вставляю:

```
<script src="https://site.ru/load.js?id=1"></script>
```

Хочу сделать чтобы в файле `load.js` определяло, какой **id** передали при вызове скрипта, и сделать там условие типа:

```
if (id == 1) { alert('1'); }
```

Буду благодарен за информацию.

Comment: Ну не знаю, например генерировать JS через тот же самый PHP?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292372/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-script-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать `document.currentScript`

```
<script src="1.js?id=1" arg_id="2"></script>
```

1.js:

```
console.log((new URL(document.currentScript.src)).searchParams.get('id')); // 1
console.log(document.currentScript.getAttribute('arg_id')); // 2
```